# Bool vector 2D array using in If condition

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check if an element in a bool vector 2D array is false or not.
Initialized 2d bool array:

```
vector<vector<bool>> *visited;
visited[row][col];
memset(visited, false, sizeof visited);

if (!visited[row][col]) //error: no operator "!" matches these operands
```

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Creating a pointer here is nonsense, use `vector<vector<bool>> visited;` instead. Also you're ought to populate your vectors before accessing them, `memset(visited, false, sizeof visited);` isn't reallay a suitable way to do that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Some reason you're answering in the comments section?

Comment: Assumind second line of code is invalid, the `visited` is a pointer not an 2d array.

Comment: @KamilCuk It's not invalid, but it doesn't do what the OP thought.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure. Answering doomed off-topic questions isn't a good idea.

Comment: Then something wrong with memset(visited, false, sizeof visited);

Comment: @TranHuynh There's a lot wrong with your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then don't, but doing it in the wrong place is double-bad. You know this.

Comment: @Light I believe I picked up that behavior from you a couple of years ago ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Doubt it!!

Answer (score 1):

You did not create a 2D bool array.

You did not even create a 2D bool vector.

You created a *pointer* to such a thing, left it uninitialised, then tried to use it in several different ways (including sizing it by accessing invalid elements).

Don't do that.

Just create your vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> visited;
```

… then use it in the normal way (which does *not* include blatting them with C's `memset`!).

You can size them like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> visited(col, std::vector<bool>(row));
```

(yuck!)

And then your attempted access at the end is out-of-bounds because indexes are 0-based.

I would however caution against 2D vectors in the general case (they have a terrible memory layout) — prefer 1D vectors if your data is rectangular; you can always map 2D indexes on top of that 1D "address space".

Comment: So how can I make a bool 2D array and initialize all elements with "false" value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Tran Huynh By

```cpp
vector<vector<bool>> visited(rows, vector<bool>(cols));
```

It's By Default initialize all the elements to false